# Rapahel js bar chart add label to X and Y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael

Here is what i have got so far with help of stackoverflow answers.
I am able to add description to bars on the bar chart but now struggling with putting label and scale on Y axis.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var r = Raphael("diagram"),
    data3 = [25, 20, 13, 32, 15, 5, 6, 10],
    txtattr = { font: "24px 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif", fill: "rgb(105, 136, 39)" };
    r.text(250, 10, "Sample Chart").attr(txtattr);
    var bc = r.barchart(10, 10, 500, 400, data3,
    {
        stacked: false,
        type: "sharp"
    });
    bc.attr({ fill: "#2f69bf" });
    var x = 1;

    labelBarChart(r, bc,
             ['abc', 'b', 'card', 'd', 'elph', 'fun', 'gurr', 'ha'],
             { fill: "#2f69bf", font: "16px sans-serif" }
    );
};

function labelBarChart(r, bc, labels, attrs)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < bc.bars.length; i++)
    {
        var bar = bc.bars[i];
        var gutterY = bar.w * 0.4;
        var labelX = bar.x;
        var labelY = bar.y + bar.h + gutterY;
        var labelText = labels[i];
        var labelAttr = { fill: "#2f69bf", font: "16px sans-serif" };
        r.text(labelX, labelY, labelText).attr(labelAttr);
    }
}
```

I would like the graph to look like this with description and units on Y Axis, don’t need anything fancy like emboss effects etc.

![image: Sample]

Comment: Did you have any luck with this friend? Because I also want to write the axis names on the chart, but I do not know why

Comment: @JimBlum no luck mate but i am working on alternate solutions...its appalling that i haven't got any responses on stack here when there are so many people recommending to use this library on issues of IE.

Comment: yes. I try to use it, but is really buggy, and limited at what can offer... I posted over 6 questions about graphael here, and I got answer only at one... Thanks a lot for answering me dude :)

Comment: @Jim Just wanted to update i ended up using jqPlot for the job since i dont have complex graphs or loads of data points for rendering, it uses excanvas for drawing and jqplot's performance degrades linearly with number of data points for IE. 

Also the previous developer had loads of javascript sitting client side performing operation on arrays in loop which i ported to server side code. 

IE8 javascript engine was bigger culprit here than its VML api. I ended up with speed boost of about 8-10 times and jqplot has lots of plugins to make your life easy :)

Comment: thanks a lot friend. I also changed library. I am using D3 now :) Raphael was too hard to handle